# Json.Net deserialize IDictionary<int,MyClass>

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize a response below:

```
{
1: { 'a': 'anything', 'b': 987, ... },
2: { 'a': 'something', 'b': 123, ... }
}
```

I create a MyClass which maps all properties in the { 'a': 'anything', 'b': 987, ... } and use IDictionary to try to deserialize it. Json.Net is able to map the right key but unfortunately the value is empty.

I have no control over the json response, so I can't make it easier for Json.Net.

How can I do it? A custom converter?

Cheers,
LD

Comment: Actually it was Reshaper's refactor. It made my properties to private set. I didn't look at my class definition after the refactor.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Here's the code I ran in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{ 1: { 'a': 'anything', 'b': 987, }, 2: { 'a': 'something', 'b': 123, } }";
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<int, MyClass>>(json).Dump();  
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class MyClass 
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

The dump prints:

```
Dictionary<Int32,MyClass> (2 items)
Key Value 
1 MyClass4 
UserQuery+MyClass 
   A anything 
   B 987 

2 MyClass4 
UserQuery+MyClass 
    A something 
    B 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what the problem is. The following console application works just fine:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"
        {
            1: { ""a"": ""anything"", ""b"": 987 },
            2: { ""a"": ""something"", ""b"": 123 }
        }";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<int, MyClass>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(result[2].A);
    }
}
```